# Did Leia recognise the name Skywalker when Luke rescues her?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

When Luke rescues Leia in *A New Hope* he introduces himself as Luke Skywalker, Leia then questions him by saying who? Which suggests to me she has heard the name before.

So where does she recognise the name from?

Seems unlikely that she would have known anything about Anakin.

Answer (score 9):

All signs point to her not recognising the name. Her response was one of slightly confused (but polite) enquiry as to whether his name is one that she *should* know.

The official novelisation has a very slightly different phrasing that makes this clearer.

> “What? Oh—the uniform.” He removed the helmet, regaining a little composure at the same time. “I’ve come to rescue you. I’m Luke Skywalker.”
>   **“I beg your pardon?” she said politely.**
>   “I said, I’ve come to rescue you. Ben Kenobi is with me. We’ve got your two ’droids—”
>   **The uncertainty was instantly replaced by hope at the mention of the oldster’s name.** “Ben Kenobi!” She looked around Luke, ignoring him as she searched for the Jedi. “Where is he? Obi-wan!”
>
> <sub><sup>[A New Hope: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: Do newer (i.e. Disney canon) novelizations agree with this? The original 1977 novelization had lots of non-canon elements in it even by the time *Return of the Jedi* came out.

Comment: @Thunderforge - The scene is absent in the latest (Disney-compatible) novelisation since we're following Han at that point in the proceedings. The scene does occur in the (original) junior novelisation but it's basically a shot-for-shot description of the film

Comment: I detected no recognition beyond realizing he wasn't a real stormtrooper, until Kenobi was mentioned - then she galvanized. Also RoTJ suggests she has only images as memory of her mother (although this could be her adoptive mother) - and RoTS shows a baby with no possibility of remembering any skywalker name.